# The 'defaultInputValue' prop of AsyncSelect in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

```
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

<AsyncSelect
              cacheOptions
              isClearable={false}
              defaultInputValue={doctor.name}
              loadOptions={async (search, callback) => {
                const doctors = await fetchDoctors(search);
                const doctorsList = doctors.map(item => ({
                  ...item,
                  label: item.doctorName,
                  value: item.doctorName,
                }));
                callback(doctorsList);
              }}
              backspaceRemovesValue
              placeholder='Search for a doctor...'
              onChange={async (newVal) => {
                const updatedOrder = { ...order };
                updatedOrder.doctorId = newVal.id;
                if (newVal.organization) {
                  updatedOrder.organization = newVal.organization;
                } else {
                  updatedOrder.organization = '';
                }
                updateOrderRemote(updatedOrder, newVal);
              }}
/>
```

The 'defaultInputValue' prop on the initial render gets passed with an undefined or empty string or a string.

However, after some interval `doctor.name` is available, however the `defaultInputValue` does not update hence maintaining the value on initial render.

Comment: *Changing the value of `defaultValue` attribute after a component has mounted will not cause any update of the value in the DOM.* - from [docs on default-values](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values). Try to make it controlled by providing `value` instead of `defaultValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Ardalan Nahavendi I went the local state route.

But touching the `inputValue` prop caused another set of problems, so I went with the `value` prop.

Code:

```
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

  const [doc, updateDoctor] = useState({ label: doctor?.name, value: doctor?.name });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (doctor.doctorName) { //at initial render the doctor prop gets the 'doctorName' key 
      updateDoctor({ label: doctor?.doctorName, value: doctor?.doctorName });
    } else {
      updateDoctor({ label: doctor?.name, value: doctor?.name });
    }
  }, [doctor]);

<AsyncSelect
  cacheOptions
  isClearable={false}
  value={doc}
  loadOptions={async (search, callback) => {
    const doctors = await fetchDoctors(search);
    const doctorsList = doctors.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      label: item.doctorName,
      value: item.doctorName,
    }));
    callback(doctorsList);
  }}
  backspaceRemovesValue
  placeholder="Search for a doctor..."
  onChange={async (newVal) => {
    updateDoctor(newVal); //has the label and value present due to loadOptions
    const updatedOrder = { ...order };
    updatedOrder.doctorId = newVal.id;
    if (newVal.organization) {
      updatedOrder.organization = newVal.organization;
    } else {
      updatedOrder.organization = '';
    }
    updateOrderRemote(updatedOrder, newVal);
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
1- You can make the render of the whole `<AsyncSelect {...props} />` conditional to availability of `doctor.name` (which i assume is a state). Which i guess is not ideal for you.
2- You should pass `inputValue` prop instead of defautInputValue. Because as far as i know, default value is only passed in first render. So you need to change your `onChange` prop's function aswell to change the state that is being used as an initial value

Comment: I've tried doing this, but this causes another problem where my newly selected option disappears on selecting...